# Can I fire an Event when I tab out of a textbox without entering a value?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an `ASP.NET Webform (C#)` that has a textbox on it. I would like to know if there is a way to fire an event when the user tabs off the textbox without entering a value?

I set `Autopostback=True` and `CauseValidation=true`. If i enter anything in the textbox it fires the `TextChanged` event which is fine. But if they tab without entering anything nothing happens.

Any Ideas?

thank you

Comment: use onclientclick check inside that whether value is empty or not..

Comment: [This](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=109) link has an exapmle that can help you

Comment: You can get those functions via client side Javascript, if this will suffice. Clientside Validation is sure possible, if this is what you want. Check out http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/ for that matter.

Comment: i used the "Onblur" function in javascript but not sure what to do inside my function. I want to read my table and get the next assigned value if its blank but want to do that in aspx.cs. Not too familiar with jscript.

Answer (score 1):

You csn handle Lost focus event on client side (js), then cause postback or run ajax request if you need server side code.

Answer (score 1):

There is an event called OnBlur in which you can use when the user doesn't enter any value.

Textbox OnBlur event fires when user leaves the textbox.

Use something like this.

in OnBlur add a javascript function as per your requirement.

Comment: I don't see this Event anywhere.